# external print function how compile

Tags: c++, gcc

I created two Files where the second File should print a std::vector.

That's my main.cpp:

```
#include <vector>
int main() {

std::vector<int> vec;
vec.push_back(1);
vec.push_back(2);
vec.push_back(3);
vec.push_back(4);
vec.push_back(5);
return 0;
}
```

That's the print.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>

template <typename T> void printVec(T vec) {
std::copy(vec.begin(), vec.end(), std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout, " "));
std::cout << std::endl;
}

template void printVec< std::vector<int> >(std::vector<int> t);
```

I compiled those files with:

```
g++ -g main.cpp -o main.o
g++ -g -c print.cpp -o print.o
g++ -o main main.o print.o
```

and get following error

```
main.o: In function `_start':
(.text+0x0): multiple definition of `_start'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.6/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o:(.text+0x0): first defined here
main.o: In function `_fini':
(.fini+0x0): multiple definition of `_fini'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.6/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/crti.o:(.fini+0x0): first defined here
main.o:(.rodata+0x0): multiple definition of `_IO_stdin_used'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.6/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o:(.rodata.cst4+0x0): first defined here
main.o: In function `__data_start':
(.data+0x0): multiple definition of `__data_start'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.6/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o:(.data+0x0): first defined here
main.o: In function `__data_start':
(.data+0x8): multiple definition of `__dso_handle'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.6/crtbegin.o:(.data+0x0): first defined here
main.o: In function `_init':
(.init+0x0): multiple definition of `_init'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.6/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/crti.o:(.init+0x0): first defined here
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.6/crtend.o:(.dtors+0x0): multiple definition of `__DTOR_END__'
main.o:(.dtors+0x8): first defined here
/usr/bin/ld: error in main.o(.eh_frame); no .eh_frame_hdr table will be created.
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

How am I supposed to get it to run?

Comment: Are you sure, there is no second main() function in your main.cpp? The linker complains about double defined symbols. This has very likely nothing to do with your print function.

Comment: You missed a -c in the compilation of main.cpp.

Answer (score 6):

Change:

```
g++ -g main.cpp -o main.o
g++ -g -c print.cpp -o print.o
g++ -o main main.o print.o
```

to:

```
g++ -g -c main.cpp -o main.o
g++ -g -c print.cpp -o print.o
g++ -o main main.o print.o
```

Or alternatively you can just combine all 3 operations into one (and enable warnings while you're at it):

```
g++ -g -Wall -o main main.cpp print.cpp
```

Comment: Any reason why one command `g++ -g -o main main.cpp print.cpp` wouldn't work?

Comment: @john: thanks, yes, that would do it all in one go - I'll add that to the answer as an alternate solution.

Comment: @PaulR Where can I go to learn to use command-line arguments?

Comment: @john None I can think of. The former make sense in large projects, so that you don't have to recompile everything.

Comment: @david Start with `g++ --help` and continue to the [GCC manual](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.7.1/gcc/)